# Does DLL size matter?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, dll

One of my colleague asked me a question:

> "I want a small portion of the c# dll (probably a helper function he
> may ask) to be used in my project, do i need to use whole package? But
> seems like to be it's size is high. so will it make any issues related
> to performance?"

But i said **NO**. The reason for my answer was:

> "Suppose we are building a web application contains of 200 pages and
> everything will be finally converted to a single dll. Do you survive a
> page / portion of dll for each request? No! we built as a single
> assembly(application) and use. The same answer applied here".

Am i right? or is really making any difference?

Every library packed as a component to survive for a different purpose of a different need. How come a performance issue will come over?

Is there any article says about loading big assembly and response time?

Comment: How about measuring the impact first and then discussing it instead of conjecturing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's better to have a single large DLL than many smaller DLLs - the size of the DLL doesn’t really matter. The cost of loading a large DLL is basically equal to loading a small DLL.